# Как правильно делать редирект JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет! Есть форма, данные которые отправляются на сервер webapi и при успешном выполнении запроса идет редирект на другую страницу клиентского сервера. Код:

```
$('#form').submit(() => {
        let formData = new FormData($('#form')[0]);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            url: 'http://localhost:57803/api/save',
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            cache: false,
            success: () => {
                window.location.href = '/home/index';
            },
            error: (e) => {
                $("#btnSubmit").prop("disabled", false);
                $('#error').text('Произошла ошибка во время создания записи, попробуйте позже.');
                console.log('Error: '+ e.responseText);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Так же есть запрос на клиентский сервер для получения данных:

```
function loadItems() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'home/getitems/' + page,
        statusCode: {
            200: (data) => {
                    $('#tbody').append(data);
                    page++;
            },
            404: () => { $('#result').attr('class', 'text-info').text('Больше нет данных.') },
            500: () => { $('#result').attr('class', 'text-danger').text('Произошла ошибка, попробуйте позже!') }
        }
        });

};
```

Все работает хорошо, но если после успешной отправке формы происходит редирект, то при отправке запроса на получение данных формируется неправильная ссылка вида https://localhost:44377/home/home/getitems/1, т.е. лишний фрагмент "/home/". Если убрать редирект, то все норм. Не могу понять в чем причина такого поведения

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать что то вроде

```
window.location.href = window.location.host + '/home/index';
```

Comment: спасибо за направление на верный путь)

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему тем, что везде, где идет запрос на клиентский сервер указал url window.location.origin + '[controller]/[action]'